# Desktop shortcuts via a GPO

Tags: windows-7, shortcut, group-policy

i'm trying to create a "restart" & "shutdown" shortcuts on the desktop on a test machine (Win 7) with a GPO. the "shutdown" icon appears on the test client desktop but not the restart icon.

'Restart' Shortcut item settings set as below:

```
Target type: File System Object
Shortcut Path: %DesktopDir%\Restart
Target path: %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe -r
Icon path: %SystemRoot%\system32\Shell32.dll
Icon index: 27
Shortcut key: None
Run: Normal Window
```

the only difference between the two shortcuts is the "-r" for the restart target path.

a bit stumped here!

Answer (score 0):

Since the command has a "-r" parameter, it may be using the string as long as it does not encounter a space.....

Could we see the actual way the GPO is written ? We are also trying to use GPO to create shortcuts (or URLs) on end-user desktops. Could you put either single or double quotes around the entire command ? Would that make a difference ?